# Nuxt3 application using @nuxtjs/apollo 5 erroring on Safari 12.1

Tags: safari, apollo, apollo-client, nuxt3

When I try to open my app in safari 12.1, it renders a blank page with a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token'.'`. The nuxt app seems to be loading, but apollo requests seem to be not firing.

I thought it was an issue related to the fact that the code was not taking into consideration the specific safari version when transpiling, but even if I target that specific version, I would still get the error. I believe that this is directly related to the fact that the nuxt apollo version does not simply work on safari 12.1. Anyone has any idea on how to fix it?

```
"nuxt": "^3.7.1",
"nuxtjs/apollo": "5.0.0-alpha.4",
"apollo/client": "3.8.3",
"vite": "^4.4.9"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.